# Pooling glmers of imputed datasets

Tags: r, lme4, r-mice

The problem:

I have a dataset, with some missing predictor values. I'd like to pool `glmer` models together which have been applied to these imputation sets. I'm using the `mice` package to create the imputations (I've also used `amelia` and `mi` too with no success). I'd like to extract the fixed effects primarily.

Using the `pool()` function within the mice package returns the error:

```
Error in qhat[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I've tried to use and adapt a previous rewrite of the `pool()` function here:

https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/pull/5

There's probably an obvious solution I'm overlooking!

Here's an example:

```
# 1. create data (that can be replicated and converge later)

data = data.frame(x1=c(rep("1",0.1*1000), rep("0",0.5*1000), 
                       rep("1",0.3*1000), rep("0",0.1*1000)), 
                  x2=c(rep("fact1",0.55*1000), rep("fact2",0.1*1000), 
                       rep(NA,0.05*1000), rep("fact3",0.3*1000)),
                  centre=c(rep("city1",0.1*1000), rep("city2",0.2*1000), 
                           rep("city3",0.15*1000), rep("city1",0.25*1000), 
                           rep("city2",0.3*1000)                          ))

# 2. set factors
data = sapply(data, as.factor)

# 3. mice imputation 
library(mice)
imp.data = mice(data, m=5, maxit=20, seed=1234, pri=F) 

# 4. apply the glmer function
library(lme4)
mice.fit = with(imp.data, glmer(x1~x2+(1|centre), family='binomial'))

# 5. pool imputations together
pooled.mi = pool(mice.fit)
```

The other function I've applied at step 4 is below, in the hope it'd create an object amenable to `pool()`.

```
mice.fit = lapply(imp.data$imp, function(d){ glmer(x1~x2+(1|centre), data=d, 
                                                   family='binomial')        })
```

I've got a work around that involves using a meta-analysis model to pool the results of each of the fixed effects of the `glmer` models. That works- but it'd be much better to have the Rubin model working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Just Works for me after making my own fork of `mice`, pulling the extended version you referenced above into it, and cleaning it up a little bit: try

```
devtools::install_github("bbolker/mice")
```

and see how your process goes after that.  (If it works, someone should submit a reminder/new pull request ...)

Comment: Dear Ben,

Sadly, when I try your command above (R version 3.3.0, mice_2.30, lme4_1.1-12), I get following error message „Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build mice“.


Best regards

Comment: you need to have Rtools installed.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but I am using a mac (mac os 10.11.6). As far as I know there is no Rtools for macintosh.

Comment: "Rtools for MacOS" = "XCode" (see https://www.rstudio.com/products/rpackages/devtools/ and search for XCode)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference between an object of class "glmerMod" and "lmerMod"? I am unfamiliar with that package lme4. But if there is no difference, you can change the class of the mice.fit analyses to "lmerMod" and then it should run fine.